# JQuery: Setting Property Based on Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-api, okvideo

I have the following JQuery properties:

```
    $(function () {
        $.okvideo({
            source: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PDL7qeeujQ',
            onReady: function () { console.log('onready') },
            onPlay: function () { console.log('onplay') },
            onPause: function () { console.log('pause') }
        });
    });
```

What I would like to do is pause the video when a user clicks a link (anchor tag) titled 'Pause'. Is this possible? Even an example with an alert to show how onPause gets called would be helpful. I can figure out the logic for actually pausing the video.

Comment: https://github.com/okfocus/okvideo

Comment: Look at their api and see how to pause it.

Comment: Looks like okvideo makes player events available, but doesn't attempt to control the player. You'd have to use YouTube's api as a callback on `onPause()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem to be exposing a global variable named `player`, which stores the API of the current provider (*youtube/vimeo/etc..*)

You need to find how to call `pause` through that.

For vimeo it would be `player.api('pause')` and `player.api('play')` to resume.

For youtube it would be `player.pauseVideo()` and `player.playVideo()`.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/7pQBn/